# Windows 10 throttles Bash network ops when not focused

Tags: networking, windows-10, terminal, microsoft-virtual-pc, throttling

I'm trying to rsync a large (90GB) file to my desktop. I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to do that, since it's WAY more performant than cygwin-virtualized rsync or similar

The problem I'm running into is that when I leave the terminal that's running rsync alone, the transfer speed drops from ~7Mb/s to ~50Kb/s. As soon as I click and bring the terminal to the foreground, however, the transfer speed goes right back up to 7Mb/s.

This leads me to believe that Win10 is somehow CPU or network throttling my process when it believes that the terminal is no longer 'active'.

Has anyone experienced this, or know how to prevent it?